# How to apply not equal to with Linq XName

Tags: c#, xml, linq

ried this to fetch the tag other than "Vehicle tag"

```
 document.Descendants(s0 + "Vehicles").Elements().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Add(document.Elements().Where(d => d.Element != s0 + "Vehicles")));
```

Need to add elements other than vehicles from base xml and trying to save it as new xml file in a path.

Base Xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <Policy >
                  <PolicyNumber></PolicyNumber>
                  <Tracking>
                     <ID></ID>
                     <LocationID></LocationID>
                     <LocationName>Wheat Ridge</LocationName>
                     <LocationPhoneNumber>3034230162</LocationPhoneNumber>
                     <LocationFaxNumber></LocationFaxNumber>
                     <LocationEmailAddress></LocationEmailAddress>
                  </Tracking>
                  <CurrentTerm>

                      <MailingAddress>
                        <Type>Mailing</Type>
                        <AddressLine>PO BOX 12</AddressLine>
                        <City>LONGMONT</City>
                        <State>
                           <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                           <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                           <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                        </State>
                        <ZipCode>805</ZipCode>
                     </MailingAddress>
                     <RiskState>
                        <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                        <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                        <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                     </RiskState>
                     <EffectiveDate>2015-10-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
                     <ExpirationDate>2016-10-01T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
                     <Vehicles>
                        <Vehicle>
                           <Number>1</Number>

                           <Year>1997</Year>
                           <Make>FORD</Make>
                           <Model>F-250 HEAVY DUTY</Model>
                        </Vehicle>
                        <Vehicle>
                           <Number>3</Number>
                           <GenerateIDCard>Y</GenerateIDCard>
                           <Year>2012</Year>
                           <Make>TOYOTA</Make>
                           <Model>CAMRY L/LE/SE/XLE</Model>
                        </Vehicle>
                       </Vehicles>
                  </CurrentTerm>
            </Policy>
```

And the output should be two files

File 1 :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <Policy >
                      <PolicyNumber></PolicyNumber>
                      <Tracking>
                         <ID>1249</ID>
                         <LocationID>2001</LocationID>
                         <LocationName>Wheat Ridge</LocationName>
                         <LocationPhoneNumber>3034230162</LocationPhoneNumber>
                         <LocationFaxNumber></LocationFaxNumber>
                         <LocationEmailAddress></LocationEmailAddress>
                      </Tracking>
                      <CurrentTerm>

                         <MailingAddress>
                            <Type>Mailing</Type>
                            <AddressLine>PO BOX 12</AddressLine>
                            <City>LONGMONT</City>
                            <State>
                               <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                               <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                               <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                            </State>
                            <ZipCode>805</ZipCode>
                         </MailingAddress>
                         <RiskState>
                            <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                            <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                            <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                         </RiskState>
                         <EffectiveDate>2015-10-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
                         <ExpirationDate>2016-10-01T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
                            <Vehicle>
                               <Number>1</Number>

                               <Year>1997</Year>
                               <Make>FORD</Make>
                               <Model>F-250 HEAVY DUTY</Model>
                            </Vehicle>
                      </CurrentTerm>
                </Policy>
```

File 2 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <Policy >
                  <PolicyNumber></PolicyNumber>
                  <Tracking>
                     <ID>1249</ID>
                     <LocationID>2001</LocationID>
                     <LocationName>Wheat Ridge</LocationName>
                     <LocationPhoneNumber>3034230162</LocationPhoneNumber>
                     <LocationFaxNumber></LocationFaxNumber>
                     <LocationEmailAddress></LocationEmailAddress>
                  </Tracking>
                  <CurrentTerm>

                     <MailingAddress>
                        <Type>Mailing</Type>
                        <AddressLine>PO BOX 12</AddressLine>
                        <City>LONGMONT</City>
                        <State>
                           <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                           <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                           <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                        </State>
                        <ZipCode>805</ZipCode>
                     </MailingAddress>
                     <RiskState>
                        <ISONumber>05</ISONumber>
                        <PostalCode>CO</PostalCode>
                        <StateName>Colorado</StateName>
                     </RiskState>
                     <EffectiveDate>2015-10-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
                     <ExpirationDate>2016-10-01T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
                        <Vehicle>
                          <Number>3</Number>

                          <VehicleIdentificationNumber>4T1BF1FK3CU526945</VehicleIdentificationNumber>
                          <Year>2012</Year>
                          <Make>TOYOTA</Make>
                          <Model>CAMRY L/LE/SE/XLE</Model>
                        </Vehicle>
                  </CurrentTerm>
            </Policy>
```

But I am getting the error that we cant use != operator 
Error   2   Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XName'  c:\users\502556385\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SplitXML\SplitXML\Program.cs   31  122 SplitXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `XName`, not a string:

```
document.Descendants(XName.Get("Vehicles",s0)).Elements().ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.Add(document.Elements().Where(d => d.Name != XName.Get("Vehicles",s0)));
```

The method uses the following arguments: `XName.Get(string tagName,string namespace).`
If `s0` is really the namespace (`XNameSpace`) you need to use `s0.NameSpace` to get the stringname.

Comment: How to save it to separate file inside foreach? s0 = namespace

Comment: the following error comes : Error 1 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XName'

Comment: @rajalakshmi Quite frankly I don't see any `+` in my answer, are you sure you didn't mistype something?

Comment: It is acceptable... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Replaced s0 with namespace it is resolved. Do you have any idea how to save it as new xml files after adding element?

Comment: You can use xmlWriter with filestream or you can just call `.Save(string filepath)` something like that

Comment: Remember to vote up/accept if this answer resolved your problem :)

Comment: Not able to save file . please help